# Is there an IIS setting to hint the browser to go into compatibility mode?

Tags: html, http, iis-7

I can modify the **Document mode** that IE renders the page in, by passing in a X-UA-Compatible in the response header. I can achieve this by modifying a setting in IIS.
[image]

Similarly is there a way to modify the **Browser mode** to Compatibility view by modifying any setting in the IIS?

Shown below is what I currently see in the F12 tool in ie.

[image: f12 screenshot]

Comment: Google rules them all.

Is this what you're looking for: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deviations/archive/2009/05/07/how-to-enable-ie-8-compatibility-view-for-your-whole-web-site-or-for-specific-web-site-directories.aspx

Answer (score 5):

To configure IIS 7 on a Windows Server 2008-based computer to include a custom HTTP response header:

1. Click Start, click Administrative Tools, and then click Internet
   Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. In the connections pane, expand the node for the server, and then
   expand .
3. Click the Web site where you want to add the custom header.
4. In the Web site pane, double-click in the section IIS on HTTP Response Headers.
5. Under Actions, click Add.
6. In the Name box, type X-UA-Compatible.
7. In the Value box, type IE=EmulateIE9.
8. Click OK.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post, that just sets the Document mode, it doesn't alter the Browser mode.

Comment: To use the latest emulation mode, use `IE=Edge`. See [X-UA-Compatibility Meta Tag and HTTP Response Header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking into this issue and found my answer here:

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/19/internet-explorer-8-document-and-browser-modes/

From that site:

> There doesn’t appear to be any other way that and end user can trigger Internet Explorer 7 mode. As such, it appears that this is just a convenience tool for developers that frees us from needing to and so it appears to be a tool used primary for developers

The same thought can be applied to IE10 I guess. It's rather frustrating, but I hope it helps.